# How to change AppBar Title in a bottom navigation screen while switching the screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-appbar

I Have created a Bottom NavigationBar Screen and i want change the AppBar title as the screen changes from navigation screen tab. Here i have created method in it a switch case to change the AppBar title. but it throws an error : Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'RxString' in type cast). i also tried removing cast 'as RxString' and changing the appBartitle to String.

> Navigation Screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:onyx/app/modules/location/views/location_view.dart';

import 'package:onyx/app/modules/offers/views/offers_view.dart';
import 'package:onyx/app/modules/setting/views/setting_view.dart';

import 'package:onyx/custom_widgets/drawer.dart';
import 'package:onyx/style/style.dart';

import '../controllers/home_controller.dart';

class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  
  final screens = [
    const OffersView(
      isAppBar: false,
    ),
    const OffersView(
      isAppBar: false,
    ),
    LocationView(),
    SettingView()
  ];
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Obx(() => Text(
                controller.appBartitle.value,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ))),
      body: Obx(
        () => IndexedStack(
            index: controller.selectedtIndex.value, children: screens),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(
        () => BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.white54,
          currentIndex: controller.selectedtIndex.value,
          onTap: (index) => controller.onTapNavigationBar(index),
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), label: "Home"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.local_offer_outlined), label: "Offers"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined), label: "Location"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings_outlined), label: "Settings"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      drawer: const CDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

> Controller

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:onyx/app/modules/home/views/home_view.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var selectedtIndex = 0.obs;
  var appBartitle = "1t".obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
  }

  onTapNavigationBar(index) {
    selectedtIndex.value = index;
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        {
          appBartitle = '1t' as RxString;
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        {
          appBartitle = '2t' as RxString;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        {
          appBartitle = '3t' as RxString;
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        {
          appBartitle = '4t' as RxString;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In onTapNavigationBar method you have only changed page index and not update title on that method so just replace controller.onTapNavigationBar(index) with
controller.onTabChanged(index) it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your HomeView class is fine. There's need some changes in HomeController class.
I have corrected and it working fine as expected. The code is given below.

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var selectedtIndex = 0.obs;
  var appBartitle = "".obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  onTapNavigationBar(int index) {
    selectedtIndex.value = index;
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        appBartitle.value = '1t';
        break;
      case 1:
        appBartitle.value = '2t';
        break;
      case 2:
        appBartitle.value = '3t';
        break;
      case 3:
        appBartitle.value = '4t';
        break;
    }
  }

  void onTabChanged(int index) {
    selectedtIndex.value = index;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also come across similar requirement.

Best choice to achieve this is to make use of providers in flutter along with ChangeNotifierProvider.

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Please refer : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: you can check the above answer